# getCode of Enum of different types in JAVA

Tags: java, enums

How can I store different types in enum and accessing them without need of casting?

```
public enum PlugsEnum {

    LOCAL_DATE(LocalDate.of(9999,12,31)),
    
    CONTRACTORNAME("autoname");

    @Getter
    private final Object code;

    PlugsEnum(Object code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

}

LocalDate localDate = (LocalDate) PlugsEnum.LOCAL_DATE.getCode()
```

Comment: Read: Abstraction in OOP! And come back if you don't understand it :))

Comment: That's not how you do things. Your enum is designed wrong if you attempt to put such differing elements into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## An enum is a limited set of named objects of the same type

You misunderstand the purpose of an enum in Java. As stated in the [*Java Language Specification*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9), an enum “defines a small set of named class instances”. So all the objects named in the enum must be of the same type. That type is the `Enum` subclass on which they are declared.

For example:

- `enum Rgb { RED , GREEN , BLUE }`
- `enum CountryInUk { ENGLAND , NORTHERN_IRELAND , SCOTLAND , WALES }`
- `enum Flavor { VANILLA , CHOCOLATE , STRAWBERRY }`

Each named object in an `Enum` subclass is of the same type. So any member property you add will be present in each and every named object.

In this next example we add the member property `hex` of type `String` to each of the `Rgb` enum objects seen above.

```
enum Rgb { 
    RED( "FF0000" ) , GREEN( "00FF00" ) , BLUE( "0000FF" ) ;
    private String hex ; // Hexadecimal representation. 
    private Rgb( String hex ) { this.hex = hex ; } ;
    public String getHex() { return this.hex ; }
}
```

## Ways to associate objects

If you want to associate various objects together by name, use the other features of Java.

You could define a `Map` to track a collection of key-value pairs. See [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) by Oracle.

```
Map< String, LocalDate > contracts = new HashMap<>() ;
contracts.put( someContractorName , someHireDate ) ;
contracts.put( otherContractorName , otherHireDate ) ;
```

Or define a class to hold the parts together. If the main purpose of the class is to carry data transparently and immutably, define your class as a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).

```
record Contract ( String contractorName , LocalDate whenHired ) {}
Contract pavement = new Contract ( "Acme Pavement Company" , LocalDate.of( 2023, Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ) ;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I should clarify the purpose of my enum beforehand. I need it to store values that would be plugs for not defined values in database or DTO. I don't want the app to through exception, I still want it to process the request. May be it is not good practice, but thats what stackoverflow is also made for)